# select name of the emp who is in all projects by a certain department

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]
[image]

---

how can i modify this query to show only the name of employee who is in all the projects by dpt 17.

so far i have :

```
select fname, lname from employee where ssn in  
(
  select distinct essn from works_on b where  
                        b.pnum in ( select pnum from project where dnum = 17) 

)
```

Here is the link to my sql fiddle i created [[Link]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01c29/2/0)

Really appreciate any help.  I am trying to  understand the logic behind how it works..

Comment: this is so unclear it makes me want to cry.  what do you mean by name?  what do you mean by "all the projects"?  What do you mean by understand the logic about how it works -- is this query working (hint: no)?

Comment: @Hogan sorry.. i have added the question i am trying to solve. So far my query will give me back names of employee who works on "any" project controlled by dpt 17.. but i only want to show name of employee who is in all of them.. in my sql fiddle example.. hat would be joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is easy when you take it in steps. I suggest you run these queries and make sure you understand their results

First project data for department 17

```
 SELECT *
 FROM project
 WHERE project.dnum = 17
```

Now all the people that work on those

```
 SELECT *
 FROM project
 LEFT JOIN works_on ON project.pnumber = works_on.pno
 WHERE project.dnum = 17
```

How we want to know works_on.essn count that is equal to the total number of projects

```
 SELECT works_on.essn
 FROM project
 LEFT JOIN works_on ON project.pnumber = works_on.pno
 WHERE project.dnum = 17
 GROUP BY works_on.essn
 HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM project WHERE project.dnum = 17)
```

Easy right?

If a sub-query in having does not work you can do it with a cross join like this

```
 SELECT works_on.essn
 FROM project
 LEFT JOIN works_on ON project.pnumber = works_on.pno
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS C FROM project WHERE project.dnum = 17) SUB
 WHERE project.dnum = 17
 GROUP BY works_on.essn 
 HAVING count(*) = MAX(SUB.C)
```

Comment: How can you use a select query in having clause?

Comment: @Teja It is a sub-query, does mssql not allow that? -- I ca rewrite it as a cross join.

Comment: You are right Hogan!! Subqueries can be used in having clause... but wondering how both of ur queries and scale performance..

Comment: Thank you so much! it makes so much sense now.

Comment: @Teja -- Basically no faster way to do it -- To speed it up add some indexes. No idea how mssql optimizes but a CROSS JOIN on one row + column should be the same as a joined sub-query -- all you are doing is adding one column.  CROSS JOINS are slow when you cross join to a table with lots of rows.